# save image file on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp

I am using wamp to host a web application.

when I tried to save an image, it's not appearing.

```
 DWObject.SaveAsPNG("img/scan/ImageData.png",0);
```

DWObject is an object from a third party plugin-in. (dynamsoft image capture suite) I am using, it can capture images and show on the div.

but it seems, save image doesn't work.

I am just wondering, whether the problem is the path or something else.

Comment: This is Rachel from Dynamsoft. As Zeantsoi said, please specify an abosolution path. 

You can use the ErrorString property to get more error info. http://www.dynamsoft.com/help/ICS/Properties/prop%20ErrorString.htm

Comment: @Robert, did you have any success with the posted answer? If so, would you kindly accept the answer as correct?

Comment: Hi Rachel, I got another issue with FTP upload with Dynamsoft image suite. Just wondering if it is possible to send you an Email about the error I got? my email is cht8687 at gmail.com

Comment: Sure Robert. We will contact you via email soon. You can also find our contact info here: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Company/Contact.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're saving to a relative path, but [the docs](http://www.dynamsoft.com/help/ICS/Methods/method%20SaveAsPNG.htm) indicate that you should be passing in an absolute path. Try saving to a directory within your [current working directory](http://php.net/getcwd):

```
DWObject.SaveAsPNG(getcwd() . "/img/scan/ImageData.png", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newImage = new Image();
newImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg";
var count = 0;

function updateImage() {
    if(newImage.complete) {
        document.getElementById("theText").src = newImage.src;
        newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = "http://localhost/image/id/image" + count++ + ".jpg";
    }
    setTimeout(updateImage, 1000);
}
```